# When is the 'ack' method in the spout called in Apache Storm?

Tags: apache-storm, apache-storm-topology, storm-topology

I have a topology for processing documents with two bolts. I need to be able to make modifications a data structure stored in the spout after a document is fully processed/has made its way through the whole topology. Before learning more about Apache Storm, I believe that the 'ack' method that is implemented in the spout was only called at the end of the topology. I see now that 'ack' needs to be called in every bolt and am confused.

**Essentially, if I put custom code in the 'ack' method in the spout: when would it be executed?** Everytime the 'ack' method is called in a bolt or when the entirety of a tuple tree has been acked/once per tuple emitted per spout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ack method in the spout is only called once the tuple has been acked by all bolts downstream, not before. See [here](http://storm.apache.org/releases/2.2.0/Guaranteeing-message-processing.html). That means that your code would be executed at the time the tuple has been acked in the entirety of the tuple tree.